# Crash happening when creating custom AuthenticationStateProvider in hosted Blazor WebAssembly .net 7 app

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-7.0

I have a hosted Blazor WebAssembly app. The app uses the .net 7 individual accounts auth. In the client I am trying to inherit from AuthenticationStateProvider (so that I can access some of its protected functions and implement some of my own auth pages in Blazor instead or the default .cshtml ones), but I am running in to an issue whereby as soon as I do this I get a crash when creating a httpClient instance and I have no idea why its happening or how to fix it.

Here is my basic AuthenticationStateProvider derived class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace SiteBuddy.Client.Services
{
    public class CustomStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
    {
        public async override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
        {
            var anonymous = new ClaimsIdentity();

            return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(anonymous)));
        }
    }
}
```

Its as minimal as I could make it and it does nothing except implement the basic required GetAuthenticationStateAsync function.

In my program.cs file I add the following in order to make sure the new class gets used:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomStateProvider>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider>(s => s.GetRequiredService<CustomStateProvider>());
```

At the beginning of my program.cs file I have these two lines:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("private", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
// Add this to allow us to make anonymous calls that dont require being authenticated
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("public", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress));
```

I create 2 HttpClients; the private one is used for almost all my back end calls where authentication is used, the private one is just used for a couple of other functions where I need to allow anonymous calls.

Further down my program.cs I have this line:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("private"));
```

As soon as I registered the CustomStateProvider class, my app crashes as soon as I try to create an instance of the 'private' HttpClient. Note that the public one is working just fine, its just the private one that causes a crash. I cant create it using the IHttpClientFactory and any time a class is created where the client is injected it crashes with the exact same error. This is the error:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: Specified cast is not valid. System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.WebAssemblyAuthenticationServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__0`3[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationState, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=7.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteUserAccount, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=7.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.ApiAuthorizationProviderOptions, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=7.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].<AddRemoteAuthentication>b__0_0(IServiceProvider sp)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext,
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=7.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object,
> System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, RuntimeResolverContext argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope
> serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext argument)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext,
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=7.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object,
> System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, RuntimeResolverContext argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite
> transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext argument)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler](IServiceProvider provider)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.HttpClientBuilderExtensions.<>c__4`1[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler,
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication,
> Version=7.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].b__4_1(HttpMessageHandlerBuilder
> b)

It appears to be some kind of circular dependency issue, but I dont understand how that can be happening when I have added practically no code at all to CustomStateProvider.

Can anyone cast any light on what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

You have problems with both inheritance and registration.

Here's an example custom provider.  Note adding your extra stuff to the provided `ClaimsPrincipal`.

```cs
public class CustomAuthenticationStateProvider : RemoteAuthenticationStateProvider
{
    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var authState = await base.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = authState.User;
        
        // Get your custom data - in this case some roles

        // add some new identities to the Claims Principal
        user.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>() { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin") }));
        user.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>() { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User") }));

        // return the modified principal
        return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user));
    }
}
```

Which you register like this:

```cs
//other registrations

//Last one so it overrides the default loaded provider
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthenticationStateProvider>();
```

Comment: The base.GetAuthenticationStateAsync() is abstract so it is not possible to call it like that. I have also already tried registering things in the way that you mention with no change in the outcome. I don't think that doing a different implementation of GetAuthenticationStateAsync is going to resolve this problem to be honest. I found some other posts from people with the exact same issue. This one here is particularly interesting https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/29487 and seems to suggest he solved it by removing AddApiAuthorization and making a custom HttpMessageHandler.